# Cannot create identity provider with nonexistent Sitecore domain "Facebook"

Tags: sitecore-client, habitat

After publishing the fresh Habitat project to Sitecore 9.1.1 fresh instance, I am facing the below error. I tried but failed to solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Cannot create identity provider with nonexistent Sitecore domain "facebook"
```

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Cannot create identity
> provider with nonexistent Sitecore domain "facebook"
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the
> execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
> and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
> stack trace below.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat No I didn't. Not in any of the owin config file

Comment: Should i have to add it in Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config file

Comment: My bad...I didn't read the fresh Habitat. did you perform all the steps for the facebook login - https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started? see the last section here

Answer (score 1):

Please check your patch config file , under the identityproviders section , there identiyprovider id and param is set to facebook.

```
<identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider id="**AzureAdB2C**" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">**AzureAdB2C**</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
 <caption>AzureAdB2C</caption>
```

You could either change it to Sitecore or create a new domain in Sitecore -> domain manager with the name "facebook"

In above example , i have used AzureAdB2c as name of IdentityProvider and domain. Please change according to your setup.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution which allow me to run the sitecore without Facebook authentication.

Need to comment the below line in **Feature.Accounts.config** file. This helped me to solve my issue.

```
<identityProvider id="Facebook" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <param desc="name">Facebook</param>
                <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                <caption>Facebook</caption>
                <domain>facebook</domain>
                <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                </transformations>
            </identityProvider>
```

and

```
<owin.identityProviders>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Infrastructure.Pipelines.IdentityProviders.Facebook, Sitecore.Feature.Accounts" resolve="true" />
        </owin.identityProviders>
```

In Habitat.Website.config comment the below line

```
<identityProvidersPerSites>
            <mapEntry name="habitat" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                <sites hint="list">
                    <site>habitat</site>
                </sites>
                <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                    <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Facebook']"/>
                </identityProviders>
                <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                    <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
                </externalUserBuilder>
            </mapEntry>
        </identityProvidersPerSites>
```